# Как сделать включение модального окна после отправки формы?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы после отправки формы открывалось модальное окно? Может через класс active сделать как? Заранее спасибо!

HTML Модального окна:

```
<section class="modal active" id="modal">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="wrapper-modal">
                <div id="overlay"></div>
                <div id="modal-window">
                    <div class="modal__content">
                        <h3 class="modal__title">
                            Заказ принят!
                        </h3>
                        <p class="modal__text">
                            Мы скоро свяжемся с вами, чтобы обсудить детали. Ожидайте!
                        </p>
                        <div>
                            <button id="btn-close">Супер! Жду!</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

PHP Отправка формы:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $token = "1507575207:AAHn5i7qFZhtHIi827V_ngMAhuDfPilFXXE";
    $chat_id = "-492501252";

    if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['phone'])){
        $bot_url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/";
        $urlForPhoto = $bot_url . "sendPhoto?chat_id=" . $chat_id;

        if(!empty($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {

            // Путь загрузки файлов
            $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/telegramform/tmp/';

            // Массив допустимых значений типа файла
            $types = array('image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg');

            // Максимальный размер файла
            $size = 1024000;

            // Проверяем тип файла
             if (!in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $types)) {
                 $msgs['err'] = 'Запрещённый тип файла.';
                echo json_encode($msgs);
                die();
             }

             // Проверяем размер файла
             if ($_FILES['file']['size'] > $size) {
                 $msgs['err'] = 'Слишком большой размер файла.';
                echo json_encode($msgs);
                die('Слишком большой размер файла.');
             }

             // Загрузка файла и вывод сообщения
             if (!@copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path . $_FILES['file']['name'])) {
                 $msgs['err'] = 'Что-то пошло не так. Файл не отправлен!';
                 echo json_encode($msgs);
             } else {
                $filePath = $path . $_FILES['file']['name'];
                $post_fields = array('chat_id' => $chat_id, 'photo' => new CURLFile(realpath($filePath)) );
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" ));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlForPhoto);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
                $output = curl_exec($ch);
                unlink($filePath);
             }
        }

        if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
          if (!empty($_POST['name'])){
            $name = "Ссылка на канал: " . strip_tags($_POST['name']) . "%0A";
          }
        }

        if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {
          if (!empty($_POST['phone'])){
            $phone = "Телеграм для связи: " . strip_tags($_POST['phone']) . "%0A";
          }
        }

        if (isset($_POST['theme'])) {
          if (!empty($_POST['theme'])){
            $theme = "Тема: " .strip_tags($_POST['theme']);
          }
        }
        // Формируем текст сообщения
        $txt = $name . $phone . $theme;

        $sendTextToTelegram = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}");
        if ($output && $sendTextToTelegram) {
            $msgs['okSend'] = 'Спасибо за отправку вашего сообщения!';
            echo json_encode($msgs);
        } elseif ($sendTextToTelegram) {
            $msgs['okSend'] = 'Спасибо за отправку вашего сообщения!';
            echo json_encode($msgs);
          return true;
        } else {
            $msgs['err'] = 'Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено!';
            echo json_encode($msgs);
            die('Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено!');
        }

    } else {
        $msgs['err'] = 'Ошибка. Вы заполнили не все обязательные поля!';
        echo json_encode($msgs);;
    }
} else {
  header ("Location: /");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**js**

$.ajax
...    
success: function(json){
if(typeof json.success !== 'undefined'){
// тут покажите свой попап
//если правильно понял и Вы используете бутстрэп,
// то вроде так $('.modal').show();
} else if(typeof json.error !== 'undefined'){
return alert(json.error);
}
}, ...


**php**

if (empty($_POST['name']){ // остальные проверки аналогично
echo json_encode(['error' => "Текст ошибки"], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
exit; // прекращаем выполнения скрипта
} else { // если нет ошибок
echo json_encode(['success' => 'Отлично. Теперь откроется попап спасибо'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```